# Remap Enter to Ctrl+PrtScn followed by Enter

Tags: autohotkey

When I press Enter I first want to take a screenshot of the current Window using Greenshot, which listens to `Ctrl+PrtScn`, then I want the Enter command to work as usual.

When I press Enter I want to:

1. Wait 1 second
2. `Alt+PrtScn`
3. Wait 1 second
4. `Enter`

If it matters I mean the Enter key above Shift, not the one on the numeric keyboard. But if it complicates things remapping both of them is fine too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Enter::                ; $ Modifer needed as script sends Enter, to not trigger itself
  sleep, 1000           ; Wait 1 second
  send !{PrintScreen}   ; ! modifier equals Alt
  sleep, 1000
  send {Enter}
  return
```